# Print SimpleXMLElement Object as xml tree

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need print my SimpleXMLElement Object.

Why "level1" elements are displayed separately? The XML object looks good.

Should be:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <level1>
            <sub1>subas1 id</sub1>
            <sub2>subas2 id</sub2>
        </level1>
        <name>car</name>
        <cat>cat1</cat>
    </item>
</items>
```

But final result is:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <level1>
            <sub1>subas1 id</sub1>
        </level1>
        <name>car</name>
        <cat>cat1</cat>
        <level1>
            <sub2>subas2 id</sub2>
        </level1>
    </item>
</items>
```

Object:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [level1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [sub1] => subas1 id
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [sub2] => subas2 id
                        )

                )

            [name] => car
            [cat] => cat1
        )

)
```

Comment: It would be more useful to show how you create your XML data,

Comment: The `print_r` output shows **level1** as an array of two elements, so I'd expect it to render as two separate tags. But yes, it's hard to diagnose this without knowing how you are constructing the object.

Comment: Would [the __toString()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) function work?

Comment: @NigelRen, my source is SimpleXMLElement Object.

Answer (score 1):

Given the expected XML, your `print_r()` dump should look like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [level1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [sub1] => subas1 id
                    [sub2] => subas2 id
                )

            [name] => car
            [cat] => cat1
        )

)
```

([Test code](https://3v4l.org/ASCoI))

So you must have made a mistake while creating the document. Most likely, you've added extraneous square brackets. Please compare:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<items />');
$xml->item->id = 1;
$xml->item->level1->sub1 = 'subas1 id';
$xml->item->level1->sub2 = 'subas2 id';
$xml->item->naem = 'car';
$xml->item->cat = 'cat1';
```

... with:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<items />');
$xml->item->id = 1;
$xml->item->level1[]->sub1 = 'subas1 id';
$xml->item->level1[]->sub2 = 'subas2 id';
$xml->item->naem = 'car';
$xml->item->cat = 'cat1';
```